# What bonus does Energy Shield receive from Telekinesis?

Tags: diablo-ii, diablo-ii-resurrected

The games tells me that energy shield receives a bonus from telekinesis. But it does not say anything about the bonus. What bonus does energy shield get from telekinesis?

When I play with the Character Planner, I can not see any difference either.

This is energy shield level 20 with telekinesis level 1.

[image: character planner]

And this is enery shield level 20 with telekinesis level 20.

[image: character planner]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Telekinesis](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Telekinesis_(Diablo_II)) gives synergy to:

> Energy Shield: reduces Mana lost per point of Life by 0.0625 per level

Users of *Energy Shield* will probably find themselves maxing out *Telekinesis* for its unwritten synergy: each point into Telekinesis makes the points of Mana lost per damage ratio of Energy Shield 0.0625 more effective.
16 points are needed in *Telekinesis* to make 1 point of damage consume 1 point of Mana, down from 2.